# Servicio Web Local Windows

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webservice

Estoy tratando de crear un servicio local de windows en vb con asp.net. siguiendo [este ejemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

En uno de los pasos dice:

> In the designer, click ServiceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual Basic
>   project, or serviceProcessInstaller1 for a Visual C# project. Set the
>   Account property to LocalSystem. This will cause the service to be
>   installed and to run on a local service account.

¿Saben como puedo establecer la propiedad Account a LocalSystem? Gracias.

Comment: Has seguido los pasos uno por uno? Has llegado a crear el instalador?

Comment: no es una propiedad del instalador?

Comment: y de paso.. Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Y ahora que lo pienso...creo que estas equivocada. El ejemplo que estás siguiendo trata de un Servicio Windows. No tiene nada que ver con un servicio Web local...